# Determine orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine an orthogonal basis for the symmetric bilinear form $S(x,y)=x^TMy$ on $\mathbb{F}_3^3$. The Matrix is:
$$M =\begin{bmatrix}0& 1 &2 \\\ 1& 1& 0 \\\ 2& 0 &2\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried to calculate first the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I have calculated just one eigenvalue that's $0$, but I need more eigenvalues.
I hope someone can help me?

Comment: There aren’t any other eigenvalues. $M$ is nilpotent, as you can verify directly by computing $M^3$ or the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Trying a "Gram-Schmidt" approach without calculating $\det M-\lambda\mathbb{1}$:

Consider $S(e_2,e_2) = 1$, so take $v_1=e_2$ as the first vector of the new base. Unluckily $S(e_1,e_1)=0$, so we can't take $e_1$ as the first vector of the new base (just to be sure...).

Then consider $v_2 = e_1 - S(e_1,v_1) v_1 = e_1 - e_2$. Then $S(v_1,v_2) = S(e_2 ,e_1 - e_2) = S(e_1,e_2) - S(e_2,e_2) = 0$ and $S(v_2,v_2)=-1$: here the second vector of the basis!

Similarly, consider $v_3 = e_3 - S(v_1,e_3)v_1 - S(v_2,e_3)v_2 = e_3 + 2(e_1-e_2)$. Then $S(v_1,v_3) = S(v_2,v_3)=0$ and $S(v_3,v_3) = S(e_3 - 2(e_1-e_2),e_3 - 2(e_1-e_2)) = 0$.

---

If you want to calculate the characteristic polynomial: $|\det (M-\lambda)| = \lambda^3$, so $\lambda=0$... then you should check the kernels of $(M-\lambda)^k$ for $k=1, \ldots, 3$ and study the generalized eigenspaces. How do you want to proceed from there?